# Problems creating a Java Mobile Application project

Tags: java-me, netbeans6.7

I have installed the Netbeans 6.7 IDE with Java ME included, but cannot create a Mobile Application project from the Java ME category.  When I select the project type the wizard stops at "Finding Feature" with the message:

Not all requested modules can be enabled:
[StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.mobility.end2end.kig jarFile:C:\Program  Files\NetBeans 6.7\mobility8\modules\org-netbeans-modules-mobility-end2end-kit.jar.

I am attempting to run this on Vista Home Premium.  I have tried to run the IDE as Administrator with no luck.

I am at a loss for where to go next as I cannot seem to find any information regarding this issue.  Even if you don't have the solution any insight into this error message would be helpful.

---

I am unable so far to get the project running via the Netbeans IDE install.  I have, for the time being, installed the Java ME SDK which includes a very stripped down version of the Netbeans IDE for mobile development.

I originally had some issues starting the SDK as well on Vista.  The IDE reported that it could not connect to the device manager on localhost.  After some searching I found this link: [Java ME SDK Startup Problem](http://www.ceviktavsan.com/java-me-sdk-startup-problem/) which suggests changing the hosts file localhost entry from IPv6 to IPv4.  The fix worked perfectly and I can now compile and run code in the emulator.

This is not an optimal solution as the SDK does not include the visual design tools, however I am able to get a basic project going in the mean time.

I have given up on the 6.7 version and have instead located and installed 6.5.1.  This previous version has been working just fine and seems to do everything I need.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the exact same error today while installing NB 6.8 beta. To resolve it we need to install two plugins:

1. Java Web Applications (as mentioned by Ali above) and
2. Sun Java System Web Server 7.0

Note that these two are part of the Category called "Java Web and EE" hence the confusion that we need to install Glassfish App Server. But we need these two plugins because they are required for debugging using breakpoints in emulator. Netbeans runs a web server when we do breakpoint based debugging.

Also note that the Java Web applications needs SOAP Web Services and JavaScript Debugger plugins to run and so these plugins are also installed when you try to install it.

Comment: It did not work for me instaling Java Web Applications plugins, but reinstalling NetBeans with J2EE enabled fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked out for you, I wouldn't have been able to help now. I am mostly working on Eclipse now.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install "Java Web Applications" plugin.

Tools->Plugins->Available Plugins

Answer (score 0):

If the module is present, you should try unzipping it to check its content makes sense.

You should also be able to rebuild it from Netbeans sources.

You can also try to figure out why this happens by debugging the module loader inside Netbeans from its sources, using another IDE, presumably the latest version of Netbeans you can find without the issue.

If the module is missing, you might want to get the missing jar file from an installation of a previous version of Netbeans, see if it is compatible.

6.5.1 isn't missing any module.

back in version 5.5, the mobility module had to be downloaded and installed separately from the main IDE.

Comment: The .jar file was installed to the appropriate location.  The issue does not appear to be that files are missing from the installation, but that the module code cannot be started for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider using Eclipse for developing your J2ME app...I've written a post related to that some time ago: [here](http://blog.js-development.com/2009/02/getting-ready-for-mobile-development.html).